# I write a tableView in my view class , but it can't show the dataSource

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

> ## import "YBLeftView.h"

```
@interface YBLeftView()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIView *myLeftView;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *tableDataArray;
@property(nonatomic,strong)UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

**//initialization of property;Omitted**

```
@implementation YBLeftView

-(instancetype)init
{
    UIView *myLeftView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/3,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
    myLeftView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:26/256.f green:31/256.f blue:36/256.f alpha:0.7];

    //tableView
    UITableView *tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 114, myLeftView.bounds.size.width, myLeftView.bounds.size.height-164) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [myLeftView addSubview:tableView];
    self.tableView=tableView;
    self.tableView.delegate=self;
    self.tableView.dataSource=self;
    tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:26/256.f green:31/256.f blue:36/256.f alpha:0.7];
    tableView.separatorStyle=NO;
    //data
    NSMutableArray *tableDataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *dataArray=@[@"首页",@"日常心理学",@"用户推荐日报",@"电影日报",@"不许无聊",@"设计日报",@"大公司日报",@"财经日报",@"互联网安全",@"开始游戏",@"音乐日报",@"动漫日报",@"体育日报"];
    self.tableDataArray=tableDataArray;
    [self.tableDataArray addObjectsFromArray:dataArray];


    return myLeftView;
}
```

**#pragma mark - Table view data source**

//this line works fine ,it log the count of tableDataArray.count and tableView return the number of count

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)self.tableDataArray.count);
    return self.tableDataArray.count;
}
```

//this line doesn't work ,even

`NSLog(@"%@",_tableDataArray[indexPath.row]);`

this code. I had add the dataSource and delegate,why this happen?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID=@"reuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (!cell) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",_tableDataArray[indexPath.row]);
//    cell.textLabel.text=_tableDataArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=@"22";
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_Follow"];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

[code excuted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awks1.png)

Comment: you need reloadData

Comment: what you are trying to do ? Please tell me what you are trying to archive?

Comment: try after replacing this line `    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: i want add a tableView in leftView, and let it show the data I set. reloadData and ` UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];`doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try your code for adding tableview in left view like below:

```
UITableView *tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 114,myLeftView.bounds.size.width, myLeftView.bounds.size.height-164) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView=tableView;
    self.tableView.delegate=self;
    self.tableView.dataSource=self;
    [myLeftView addSubview:self.tableView];
    ...
    [self.view addSubview:myLeftView];
```

Try the code hope you get the result. Because giving all property to the controller after adding that in view may result in unexpected result. So, just try to add your tableview in your left view after you give all properties to it. And then Add your left view in main view. 
This may help you.
Best of luck.

Comment: [self.view addSubview:myLeftView];

self is a view, it hasn't the property of view

Answer (score 0):

Override the `initWithFrame:` method of the `UIView`. You don't have to declare a another view inside your YBLeftView. It should be this way instead:

```
@implementation YBLeftView

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:26/256.f green:31/256.f blue:36/256.f alpha:0.7];
    self.tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 114, myLeftView.bounds.size.width, myLeftView.bounds.size.height-164) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self addSubview:self.tableView];
    self.tableView.delegate=self;
    self.tableView.dataSource=self;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:26/256.f green:31/256.f blue:36/256.f alpha:0.7];
    tableView.separatorStyle=NO;
    //data
    self.tableDataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *dataArray=@[@"首页",@"日常心理学",@"用户推荐日报",@"电影日报",@"不许无聊",@"设计日报",@"大公司日报",@"财经日报",@"互联网安全",@"开始游戏",@"音乐日报",@"动漫日报",@"体育日报"];

    [self.tableDataArray addObjectsFromArray:dataArray];

    return self;
}
```

Then, when you initialize your YBLeftView, your can call the init method like this:

```
YBLeftView *leftView = [[YBLeftView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/3,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)]];
```

This way is more flexible.

For the tableView problem, I think you just declared the data array right after you added the tableview to your YBLeftView. Maybe you could try declaring it before you add/declare the tableView. Because that time, your dataArray's count should still be zero, that's why the cellForRowAtIndexPath: didn't get called.

Or you can try reloading the whole table to see if that's really case. Reloading the table would just be like:

```
[_tableView reloadData];
```